# Returning a json response from node.js to the front-end.

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, web

So, I am trying to fetch my back end code and receive the json response from the API I am querying on the back-end. It is returning an object but, my json is either buried in it or not there. I can log the data in node, I just can't send it back. I have tried res-send, res-json and res-end. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thank you for any help!

web app console response
     Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3003/father", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Front-end javascript

```
  document.querySelector('.sub').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const wordSearched = document.querySelector('.word').value;
  fetch(`/${wordSearched}`)

   .then(function(answer) {
     console.log(answer);
  const number = answer.total_results;
  console.log(number);
  const tag = document.querySelector(".tagg").innerHTML = `The word 
  ${wordSearched} was used ${number} times!`;
  return tag
  })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log(' There has been a problem with the fetch operation: ', 
  error.message);
   })});
```

Back-end node.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');

    app.use(express.static('\public'));
    app.use(morgan('short'));

    app.get('/:wordSearched', (req, res) => {
      let word = req.params.wordSearched;
      console.log(word);
    fetch(`https://api.esv.org/v3/passage/search/?q=${word}`, {
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token kkkdddd88383' // API Token
    }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
     const number = myJson.total_results;
      console.log(number);
      res.send(myJson) //cant send number??
        })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(' There has been a problem with the fetch operation: ', error.message);
         })
         });

         //local host
        app.listen(3003, () => {
         console.log('server is up on 3003');
            });
```

Comment: Please see how fetch should be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I actually just ran it without a body-parser. I am still learning...What would be the benefit of using one here?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out my issue after reading the fetch documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. I had to call:

```
      .then(function(response) {
  return response.json()
})
```

On my front-end as well. I had previously only called it on the back-end thinking is was json I was sending. Unless I made the .json() call on each end I was not going to get my answer through.